# Combining confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a collection of efficiency curves i.e. numbers between 0 and 1 as a function of a physical variable. Each efficiency point on the curve has an associated Clopper Pearson 1-sigma confidence interval.

I now need to combine these to obtain a total efficiency as a function of said variable. This means I multiply all the corresponding efficiency points together so that eff_total for point i is eff_1*eff_2*...*eff_n, etc.

How do I propagate the uncertainty in the form of these confidence intervals to eff_total?